# Change MFC executable in static library and create wrapper executable ... possible ?

Tags: visual-c++, static-libraries, wrapper

Is this possible ? And if ... what are the points of interest to achieve this ?

**Context**: We want to introduce UnitTesting to most of our applications. After some research the easiest way should be to have a static library from our existing executable. So in the project properties I changed the Configuration type to "Static library". Further I created a new project that uses this static lib, to create the executable again.

But I cannot get it to work (entry point problems). So currently I am wondering if this is even possible and if there is some sort of "howto" to make a executable wrapper for my lib.

Kind Regards 
Kevin